# Does it make sense to send the same push notification every hour for a day?

Tags: google-chrome, push, web-push

**context:** So I've implemented a push notification system which records an FCM subscription from a Google Chrome browser and stores it in a PostgreSQL JSON field... pretty standard.

I try to send these everyday at 1pm and I realised it looks like no one is receiving them. This is most likely because no-one opens their browsers at this time and according to this [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/faq), the notifications only work when the browser is open.

i.e. **It seems like my best bet is to send the notification every hour hoping the browser is open at some point**.

I would also love if someone could point me to documentation somewhere that tells me if push notifications are saved for when a user opens the browser, or that they expire after a certain amount of time

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **TTL** for notifications when you send it. Standard web push services use a TTL header expressed in seconds. If TTL is zero, then the notification is dropped if the device is not connected. If TTL is different from zero, the notification will expire after the TTL have passed.

Comment: Ah fantastic, will try that out! Sorry I can't upvote yet :(. Low reputation points